# List and List value manipulations in Erlang

Tags: list, recursion, erlang, list-comprehension, tail-recursion

I am  learning some Erlang and doing exercises from the book, so i got stuck on one of them. It`s better if i quote the whole problem and then explain what i have done so far: 
"A positive number is happy if by repeated application
of the procedure below the number 1 is reached.
1. Square each of the digits of the number
2. Compute the sum of all the squares
For example, if you start with 19:

```
 1 * 1 + 9 * 9 = 1 + 81 = 82
 8 * 8 + 2 * 2 = 64 + 4 = 68
 6 * 6 + 8 * 8 = 36 + 64 = 100
 1 * 1 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1
```

(i.e. 19 is a happy number)
How do you know when a number is not happy? In fact, every unhappy
number will eventually reach the cycle 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4,
… thus it is sufficient to look for any number in that cycle (say 4), and
conclude that the original number is unhappy.
Write the functions happy/1, and all_happy/2, which returns
whether a number is happy or not (true or false) and all happy numbers
between N and M respectively. (Hint: use the functions digitize and
sum).
Examples:

```
 happy(28) → true
 happy(15) → false
 happy(5, 25) → [7, 10, 13, 19, 23]"
```

So, I have created a digitizer/1, which given a positive number N returns a list of the digits in that number:

```
digitize(N) -> digitize1(N, []).
digitize1(N, Acc) when N > 0 -> digitize1(N div 10, [N rem 10| Acc]);
digitize1(N, Acc) when N == 0 -> Acc.
```

, and sum/1:

```
sum(N) when  N > 0 -> N + sum(N-1);
sum(0) ->   0.
```

So for the happy numbers what i have done so far is this:

```
happy(N) -> happy1(digitize(N), []).
happy1([], Acc) -> (Acc);
happy1([Head|Tail], Acc1) -> happy1(Tail, [Head * Head|Acc1]).
```

It squares the elements of the list, but i cannot come up with idea of how to sum them and do it again recursively until it reaches 1 or 4. Any help or ideas?
And for the second part(all_happy/2), in my non-competent opinion i should use list comprehension, but again, I`m not quite sure how to implement it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This exercise is cool:) I don't know if you know project Euler... If not, you will find many other small exercises like this to train erlang (or any language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I noticed is your happy1 loop can just calculate the sum directly, you don't need to make a list and then add them:

```
calculate([], Total)->
  Total;
calculate([First | Rest], Total) ->
  calculate(Rest, Total + (First * First)).
```

To the main point of your question, you can use pattern matching to detect whether or not you've reached an unhappy number or if you've reached 1.

I have a working implementation, but I'm guessing you'd like to figure out the details for yourself.  Let me know if you want me to post it.

---

Here's my solution:

```
-module(happy).

-export([happy/1]).

happy(1) ->
  happy;
happy(4) ->
  not_happy;
happy(Num) ->
  io:format("Current loop: ~p~n", [Num]),
  Digits = digitize(Num),
  happy(calculate(Digits, 0)).


digitize(N) -> digitize1(N, []).
digitize1(N, Acc) when N > 0 -> digitize1(N div 10, [N rem 10| Acc]);
digitize1(N, Acc) when N == 0 -> Acc.

calculate([], Total)->
  Total;
calculate([First | Rest], Total) ->
  calculate(Rest, Total + (First * First)).
```

Output:

```
3> happy:happy(55).
Current loop: 55
Current loop: 50
Current loop: 25
Current loop: 29
Current loop: 85
Current loop: 89
Current loop: 145
Current loop: 42
Current loop: 20
not_happy
4> happy:happy(4). 
not_happy
5> happy:happy(19).
Current loop: 19
Current loop: 82
Current loop: 68
Current loop: 100
happy
6> happy:happy(20).
Current loop: 20
not_happy
7> happy:happy(21).
Current loop: 21
Current loop: 5
Current loop: 25
Current loop: 29
Current loop: 85
Current loop: 89
Current loop: 145
Current loop: 42
Current loop: 20
not_happy
```

If you're interested in how to use a list comprehension, here's the main clause which skips the calculate method and uses the `lists:sum` function with the build list:

```
happy(Num) ->
  io:format("Current loop: ~p~n", [Num]),
  Digits = [ X * X || X <- digitize(Num)],
  happy(lists:sum(Digits)).
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I would like to see your solution to this problem, since I have tried everything I could do and I`m at the point when I just want to see and understand how it`s done. So yes please, post it if you can. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I had some inaccuracies in the original post; turns out I misread the question.  Should be correct now, let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this could not be more clear! I would up vote your answer N times if possible!  :) Comprehensions seems surprisingly easy, when it`s written and served.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that implements via tail recursion :

```
digitize(N) -> digitize1(N, [],N).
digitize1(N, Acc,M) when N > 0 -> digitize1(N div 10, [N rem 10| Acc],M);
digitize1(N, Acc,M) when N == 0 -> sum_digits(Acc,0,M).

sum_digits([],Acc,N) when Acc == 1 -> {happy,N,Acc};
sum_digits([], Acc,N) when Acc == 4 -> {unhappy,N,Acc};
sum_digits([],Acc,N) -> {digitize,Acc}, digitize1(Acc,[],N);
sum_digits([H|T],Acc,N)-> sum_digits(T,H*H+Acc,N).
```

to use:

```
1> c('test.erl').
test.erl:15: Warning: a term is constructed, but never used
{ok,test}
2> c('test.erl').
test.erl:15: Warning: a term is constructed, but never used
{ok,test}
3> c('test.erl').
test.erl:15: Warning: a term is constructed, but never used
{ok,test}
4> test:digitize(55).
{unhappy,55,4}
5> test:digitize(19).
{happy,19,1}
6> test:digitize(5). 
{unhappy,5,4}
7> test:digitize(20).
{unhappy,20,4}
8> test:digitize(21).
{unhappy,21,4}
```